# Subset is open under a subset metric $d_A$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

I have a doubt about this question:

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, and let $A$ be a subset of $X$.
> We shall consider $A$ with the subset metric dA.
> Assume that $G \subseteq A$ is open in (X,d). Show that G is open in $(A,d_A)$.

I have been proposing in my notebook something based on the fact that if an open set is a subset of another, it continues to preserve its condition. But the fact of being subjected to this new metric makes me doubt and I don't know how to interpret it very well. Could someone help me understand what could be the incidence of being under a metric other than that of the complete space $X$?

Comment: The _true_ result is "Assume $G\subseteq X$ is open in $(X, d)$, show that $G\cap A$ is open in $(A, d_A)$". What you're asked to show is a special case.

Comment: Hint: The open sets in $(A,d_A)$ are by definitions of the form $B \cap A$ where $B$ is a open set in $(X,d)$.

Comment: thanks @BrianBritosSimmari :D

Comment: @BrianBritosSimmari Not in metric spaces. There openness is not inherited from the ambient space, but induced from the inherited metric (you could argue that you inherit both openness and metric, but then you would have to prove that the two inheritances agree on what the open subsets of $A$ are, and you're back at this very exercise anyways). In topological spaces, yes, you would be right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of an open subset of a metric space is most commonly something along these lines:

> A subset $Y\subseteq X$ is open in the metric space $(X,d)$ iff, for any point $y\in Y$, there is a real number $r>0$ such that the open ball of radius $r$ centered at $y$, using the metric $d$, is contained in $Y$.

Let $g\in G$ be an arbitrary point. We want to show that there is a real number $r>0$ such that the open ball in $A$, centered at $g$ and measured according to the metric $d_A$, is contained in $G$.

We know that $G$ is open in $(X,d)$, so there is an $r>0$ such that the open ball centered at $g$ with radius $r$ according to the metric $d$ is contained in $G$.

But if we now shift to $(A, d_A)$, the open ball centered at $g$ with radius $r$ according to $d_A$ is exactly the same set as the open ball in the paragraph above. So it is necessarily still contained in $G$. This finishes our proof.